# Fabric js - How to draw cloud shape using mouse event?

Tags: fabricjs

I have been searching to draw cloud shape while mouse drag using Fabric Js. My idea is not to be like free drawing. Can anyone suggest how to draw cloud shape over canvas using fabric js mouse move up and down events?

Comment: What does this cloud shape look like? Is it a path SVG or an image? Can you provide an example?

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=cloud+shape+images&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN821IN821&oq=cloud+shap&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j69i60j0l4.5083j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 
Like this I need to draw a shape similar to cloud

Comment: Well, if it's an image, why don't you use `fabric.Image` then? You can draw it in `mouse:down` event handler

Comment: I want to draw this image in canvas using mouse events of fabric.